# md0 RAID1 can't read superblock

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid-1, array

i have a problem with my md0 array, which is an raid1 (2 mirrored USB-Sticks)

Mount gives "Can't read superblock"

cat /proc/mdstat:

```
    Personalities :
    unused devices: <none>
```

fdisk -l

```
    /dev/sdc1            2048    15679487     7838720   fd  Linux raid autodetect
    /dev/sdc1            2048    15679487     7838720   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 gives:

```
    mdadm: /dev/sdc1 misses out due to wrong homehost
    mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
```

and after several tries it seems to work with 1 drive now. How do I repair it without loss ? How do i fill /proc/mdstat if useful ?

Comment: I did a search for the "homehost" error and found http://askubuntu.com/questions/230525/raid-5-reassemble-stating-wrong-homehost .  If you have one half of a mirror and want to construct a matching half, the "mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdc1" command should start a synchronization from /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sdc1.